# Minimum voltage for a RC Oscillator

Tags: transistors, oscillator

I am trying to run an RC oscillator using a 2n3904 the circuit looks like the following.

[image]

You can see the live circuit here. [Simulation](http://goo.gl/f4F17c) I want to run it at 0-5v but I am not getting the result, I assume because the voltage is not high enough?

What would you expect the minimum voltage requirement to be for this type of circuit.

Comment: "not getting the result"? Would you go to a doctor and expect a perfect diagnosis if all that you told him was that you were ill?

Comment: It is not a simple task to design a phase shift oscillator with a BJT as an active elemnt. The reason: The feedback circuit should be decoupled from the amplifier as much as possible - otherwise the classical formulas for designing the circuit (oscillation frequency, required gain) cannot be used. In your circuit, the amplifiers output resistance is in the same region as the phase shift resistors (10k). More than that, the transistors input resistance is in parallel to the 10k DC bias resistor. It is best to simulate the loop gain vs. frequency first.

Comment: As a starting point I was trying to create the circuit found here https://www.quora.com/What-are-component-values-for-an-RC-phase-shift-oscillator-using-a-bipolar-transistor-with-a-frequency-around-1-Hz. "not getting the result" is not the question. Is 5v sufficient to drive a circuit like this is.

Comment: In the reference (quora) they have used the IDEAL formula which applies to IDEAL amplifiers only (opamp). I doubt if the author has build the circuit.

Comment: @LvW it is in fact quite difficult to have good frequency stability and low distortion with this schematics, but it is indeed quite easy to make it oscillate.

Answer (score 2):

The base voltage of the transistor must be high enough to polarize the BE junction and have some voltage on the emitter, and consequently a collector current.
The original circuit is powered at 9V, so that the base voltage is about 0.9V.
To have the same base voltage at 5V, you'd better lower the 100k resostor accordingly.

Consider also that at 5V you must recalculate the 4k7 resistor to maximize the p-p amplitude of the oscillation.

Also consider that the two resistors on the base should have a parallel value of about 10k, so it is better to also rise the 10k. Moreover, the ratio of the collector and the emitter resistors determine the DC gain, and should be mantained abt 10:1